# Get select_tag key value pair in controller after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a select box in view like this:

```
<% contact = Contacts.all.map{|x| [x.name.to_s.capitalize] + [x.id]} %>
<%= select_tag("selectedContact", options_for_select(contacts)) %>
```

and in controller getting the selected value like this:

```
contact_id = params[:selectedContact]
```

Now in some cases i need to match contact name also. Is there any way i can get both id and name of selected contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use, `[{ x[:name] => x[:id]}]`

`<% contact = Contacts.all.map{|x| [x.name.to_s.capitalize] + [{ x[:name] => x[:id]}]} %>`

In the controller,

```
contact_name = params[:selectedContact].keys[0]
contact_id = params[:selectedContact][contact_name]
```

Comment: It says syntax error, unexpected ':' in the first line

Comment: check the updated answer, `<% contact = Contacts.all.map{|x| [x.name.to_s.capitalize] + [{ x[:name] => x[:id]}]} %>`

Comment: I got the name in controller in params[:selectedContact] but not the id

Comment: Do i need to create another hidden select in view for id

Comment: check what you are getting in params, render text: params and return false

Comment: Ok i got it by concatenating id with name and later splitting it in controller. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Sravan, I did it by concatenating id with name in view and later splitting it in controller to get id and name.
In View:

```
<% contact = Contacts.all.map{|x| [x.name.to_s.capitalize] + [x.id.to_s+'_'+x.name.to_s]} %>
```

and in controller:

```
contact_id = params[:selectCPA].split('_')[0]
contact_name = params[:selectCPA].split('_')[1]
```